# What is the path to the kernel headers so I can install vmware?

Tags: kernel, vmware-player

I installed the VMware bundle on my Ubuntu 11.04 successfully but when I open it it gives me this window

[image]

and I don't know the path to this C headers.

Comment: Which Kernel are you using (check with `uname -a`). Because with the 11.04 upgrade ubuntu silently switched my kernel from linux-generic to linux-generic-pae without installing the relevant headers, which uses a different set of linux headers. As per the three responses below, using `apt-get` is the proper way to solve the issue, you just have to make sure the kernel headers are the right ones.

Comment: Zhe seems to be on the right track, but still something missing. Creating those links helps to get past the prompt for the 2.6.38.8_generic kernel headers, but then when I run VMWare Workstation (6.5.5) I get an error saying "Unable to build kernel modules. See logfile /tmp/vmware-root/setup-22414.log", and when I look in the log file it just describes the build attempt, but shows no errors, which is weird. So I tried to go the short route and reinstall from the bundle to see if doing that after creating the links solved the problem. It did not. I'm stuck. Any ideas? I thought that combining t

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

After adding the symlink, the path is `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include` (Thanks @Kariem!)

Comment: FYI, I had to do these exact steps to get VMWare Workstation working with Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear, as I did not read that from the answer: after adding the symlink, the path is `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include`

Comment: Worked on 13.04

Comment: The fact you need those is retarded - much thanks for this.

Comment: Zhe's answer + Kariem's comment are invaluable. This solved the "Unable to update runtime folder sharing status: There was an error mounting Shared Folders file system inside the guest operating system." error for me in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I used this answer to get VMWare tools running in Linux Mint 15 as well.

Comment: This works! Thank you. My question is: How did you find out what exactly to do?

Comment: @pepoluan some forum posts, read the source code and hundreds of tries :)

Comment: This is *STILL* a problem as of 14.04. Amazing.

Comment: If you try the solution in this answer and are getting 'No such file or directory' errors after attempting to 'cd', then @manikandan's answer below helps. After installing the headers, that directory should exist. See: http://askubuntu.com/a/65314/28555

Comment: when facing this issue on centos 7 (I know, this is an ubuntu site, but google brought me here and it was helpful), I had to yum install kernel-devel first, then complete the steps outlined by Zhe, then the include dir was found in /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include.

Comment: Encountered similar problem trying to install VMware tools in an old ESXi vSphere 5.x system and CentOS 7.9. Same solution. Mentioning it here in case others are struggling with a similar combination.

Answer (score 50):

Below commands are very helpful for you:

Step 1 :  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Step 2 : `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Step 3 : The path to the kernel headers is then 
`/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include`

Comment: This answer worked on my machine, Debian 8.3 i386

Answer (score 20):

Before installing Vmware Workstation you need to install build-essential and linux headers

```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and then

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

Done thats it, install Vmware Workstation now

```
 path to vm# sh Vm***.bundle
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) worked wonder. Fixed my problem, thx.

Comment: +1 I was missing build-essentials. This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 12):

There are a few files in locations that the installer doesn't expect, I run this and it works:

```
ifrantz@ifrantz:~$ cat ~/update_version.sh 
#!/bin/bash

cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

Answer (score 8):

My first guess is that you haven't installed the headers. You need to install the appropriate linux-headers package. Most likely, you need to install `linux-headers-generic`. However, if if you're running some kernel other than `linux-generic`, install the linux-headers package for that kernel.

If you've already installed the headers, they should be in `/usr/src`.

Comment: Can you provide me with the name of these headers packages?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You can search in Synaptic to find out what you're running on your machine. Most likely, your kernel is `linux-generic`. If so, install `linux-headers-generic`, which will pull in the proper packages as dependencies. The exact headers package (and paths in the filesystem) change with each kernel update. Look on your system to find out which is in use.

Comment: apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Comment: @owl, The problem with that is you'll have to reinstall the headers every time the version changes. If you install the basic linux-headers package, it's always up to date.

Answer (score 7):

Problem can be solved in two steps, after installing vmware workstation 9.X.X (in terminal):

1. `sudo apt-get install gcc`
2. `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all --appname="VMware Player" --icon="vmware-player"`

Comment: This one plus the build-essentials suggestion from answers above fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: Maybe you need to do a `sudo apt-get update` before the install

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, I was running  kernel 3.2.0-29 but only had linux-headers-3.2.0-35 in /usr/src/

```
user@ubuntu:/usr/src$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan  5 11:17 linux-headers-3.2.0-35
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jan  5 11:17 linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic

user@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35/include$ uname -a

Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_6                                                                                4 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

user@ubuntu:/usr/src$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic

user@ubuntu:/usr/src/$ cd /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib
user@ubuntu:/tmp/vmware-tools-distrib$ sudo ./vmware-install.pl
<kept hitting enter>

Enjoy, --the VMware team

done and done
```