# Low Graphics Mode error on 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, ati, graphics, xorg

**Background**

I have a dell inspiron 15r se. Step by step, I wanted to upgrade the system from 11.10 to 13.04. Up to 12.10 everything was alright, it was working very well,

**Problem**

When i did `sudo do-release-upgrade` from 12.10 to 13.04, after the upgrade unity was not working, I had only desktop visible, no menu on top or left (i am not sure how they are called). I had exactly [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285779/after-upgrading-to-13-04-unity-interface-is-not-showing).

**What I tried**

Of course I tried resetting unity, enabling unity plugin in compiz, etc, but nothing worked.

At this moment I don't really remember what I have done (I tried many different things like until 2 am in the night, i can't recall all) and now what I get is the "Low Graphics Mode" just like in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error). My graphics card is ATI, so I tried the solution offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/286775), and absolutely nothing changed.

I also tried installing linux-headers-generic, also linux-headers-'uname -r', adding a symbolic link for version.h (because it wasn't there, i did something like [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/231896)) but none of them worked.

Starting using one of the old kernels (selecting them from GRUB) does not work either, each one of them also go into low graphics mode.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6011054/) is the output from my /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: for the record, I couldn't find any solution and I had to use recovery partition to go back to 11.10.

Comment: I do not know about the model (Dell Inspiron) so please let me know if it is a 64 bit processor and if there was a linux-generic-pae installed on your system. If yes, then it has been seen to happen quite frequently in our systems.

Comment: However, in case if you find a `failsafe` kind of file in `/etc/X11` manage to delete that file by booting to command prompt and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after upgrade to the latest ubuntu.
I copied the  system files from a laptop onto a spare disk. Did a chroot from a rescue disk and fixed grub.
Booted from a usb port on my old intel box for which there are no drivers.
ctl+alt+f1  gave me a shell.
in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.cfg found autologon for user. Disabled it by inserting # at start of line.
ran dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
ran service lightdm restart
This gave me a logon screen. Changed the session to the top option (I think gdm) and was able to logon. 
Logged out and changed the session back to ubuntu unity.
Peter