# VMWare Workstation 6.5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04: Kernel Headers not found

Tags: 14.04, vmware-workstation

Installation by running `sudo ./VMware-Workstation-6.5.5-328052.x86_64.bundle` completes successfully.

However, upon attempting to run `vmware`, the following error message box is displayed:

[image]

Clicking OK then displays another error message box:

[image]

With the following log on the console:

```
Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/setup-15921.log
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmmon not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmnet not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmblock not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmci not found.
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vsock.ko
license:        GPL v2
version:        1.0.1.0-k
description:    VMware Virtual Socket Family
author:         VMware, Inc.
srcversion:     DEF0E4AC6D739CEE581C08F
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmmon not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmnet not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmblock not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmci not found.
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vsock.ko
license:        GPL v2
version:        1.0.1.0-k
description:    VMware Virtual Socket Family
author:         VMware, Inc.
srcversion:     DEF0E4AC6D739CEE581C08F
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmmon not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmnet not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmblock not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmci not found.
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vsock.ko
license:        GPL v2
version:        1.0.1.0-k
description:    VMware Virtual Socket Family
author:         VMware, Inc.
srcversion:     DEF0E4AC6D739CEE581C08F
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

(vmware-modconfig:15921): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/bta/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmmon not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmnet not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmblock not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmci not found.
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vsock.ko
license:        GPL v2
version:        1.0.1.0-k
description:    VMware Virtual Socket Family
author:         VMware, Inc.
srcversion:     DEF0E4AC6D739CEE581C08F
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

It tried this workaround:

```
sudo -s    
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux    
ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h    
ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
```

But that didn't change the aforementioned behaviour.

Any idea how to let vmware find the kernel headers and proceed to successful run?

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the tips provided below and this [Unable to run VMware - Failed to build vmnet](https://askubuntu.com/q/414783/363039) article, I proceeded as follows:

```
sudo -s    
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux    
ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h    
ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

That last `ln -s` (for version.h) indeed got me past the "kernel headers not found" error message. But now I was getting:

> Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded
>   into the kernel CANCEL / INSTALL

So, I did this step:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox open-vm-tools-dev
```

and now I am getting this:

[image]

Followed (within 1-2 seconds) by this:

[image]

I then followed by (as described in [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/444375/363039))

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xvf vmnet.tar
patch vmnet-only/filter.c < ~/vmnet313.patch
tar -uvf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmnet-only
/usr/bin/vmware
```

But I am getting the same result ("Unable to build kernel module" error message box).

If I try (as in the original solution):

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Then I am getting:

```
Stopping VMware services:
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:40:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/smp_lock.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only'
Unable to install vmmon
```

I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

which got me a lot of extra packages, but I am still receiving the last failure with *"linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory"*, etc.

So, I did:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/include/linux/smp.h /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/include/linux/smp_lock.h
```

and this made some progress as I am now failing the build/install with:

```
Stopping VMware services:
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:100:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:108:7: warning: "__FreeBSD__" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif __FreeBSD__
       ^
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:29,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:102:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:164:0: warning: "MSR_THERM2_CTL" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define MSR_THERM2_CTL       0x0000019D // Thermal Monitor 2 Control (ro)
 ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/msr.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:22,
                 from include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/compat_module.h:27,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:26:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/msr-index.h:334:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_THERM2_CTL   0x0000019d
 ^
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vcpuset.h:103:0,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:37,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:33,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:29,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:102:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:329:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:333:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:401:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:407:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_ReadIfEqualWrite64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:460:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_And’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:506:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_And64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:551:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Or’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:595:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Or64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:640:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Xor’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:684:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Xor64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:729:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Add’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:773:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:775:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Add64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:816:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Sub’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:860:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:862:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Sub64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:903:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Inc’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:945:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:947:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Inc64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:986:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Dec’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1028:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1030:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_Dec64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1069:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: At top level:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1223:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER >= 1310
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1227:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_ReadAdd64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1313:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: At top level:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1536:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1663:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER /* MSC (assume on x86 for now) */
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h: In function ‘Atomic_ReadWrite64’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:1796:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:40:0,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:100:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/busmem_def.h: In function ‘BUSMEMDEFS’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:249:20: warning: typedef ‘AssertOnCompileType’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
       typedef char AssertOnCompileType[(e) ? 1 : -1]; \
                    ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:271:7: note: in definition of macro ‘MY_ASSERTS’
       assertions \
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/busmem_def.h:69:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘ASSERT_ON_COMPILE’
            ASSERT_ON_COMPILE(sizeof(BusMemDef_BatchPageList) <= PAGE_SIZE);)
            ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/pshare_ext.h: In function ‘PSHARE_EXT’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:249:20: warning: typedef ‘AssertOnCompileType’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
       typedef char AssertOnCompileType[(e) ? 1 : -1]; \
                    ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:271:7: note: in definition of macro ‘MY_ASSERTS’
       assertions \
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/pshare_ext.h:67:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘ASSERT_ON_COMPILE’
            ASSERT_ON_COMPILE((PSHARE_HINT_UPDATES_MAX <=
            ^
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:39:0,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:41,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:104:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h: At top level:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:486:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER  /* !__GNUC__ */
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:779:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:820:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:922:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER
       ^
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:104:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:56:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif _MSC_VER  /* !__GNUC__ */
       ^
In file included from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:120:0:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/./common/hostif.h:53:7: warning: "WINNT_DDK" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #elif WINNT_DDK
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:427:15: error: ‘struct file_operations’ has no member named ‘ioctl’
    vmuser_fops.ioctl = LinuxDriver_Ioctl;
               ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: At top level:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:771:59: error: ‘SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 static spinlock_t pollQueueLock __attribute__((unused)) = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
                                                           ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1744:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘unlock_kernel’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       unlock_kernel();
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1751:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘lock_kernel’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       lock_kernel();
       ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1988:26: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘kuid_t’ and ‘kuid_t’)
       if (current_euid() == current_uid() &&
                          ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1989:20: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘kuid_t’ and ‘kuid_t’)
    current_fsuid() == current_uid() &&
                    ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1990:26: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘kgid_t’ and ‘kgid_t’)
           current_egid() == current_gid() &&
                          ^
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1991:20: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘kgid_t’ and ‘kgid_t’)
    current_fsgid() == current_gid()) {
                    ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only'
Unable to install vmmon
```

Looks like I should be giving up...

Unless you have additional ideas?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: You still may have to play all sorts of games with the headers once you get them on the old version you are trying to compile, try the latest veresion 11.

Comment: Try adding `sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h` to the list of workarounds you listed in your OP. Plus additional steps as described in [Unable to start VMWare Workstation after upgrade to 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/286326/130251)

Comment: You may also want to check this thread: [What is the path to the kernel headers so I can install vmware?](http://askubuntu.com/q/40979/366653)

Comment: Download VMware-Workstation-Full-11.0.0-2305329.x86_64.bundle . vmware has been keeping up much better with the latest kernel header changes.

Comment: @ubfan1 My license is only for version 6.5.5 and to upgrade to version 11.0.0 would cost me $150, which I can't afford right now. I will switch to VirtualBox or some other free solution. Thanks.

Comment: I use VMplayer, which is free, and meets my needs. Try it out, might be easier to keep running when kernels get upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Oracle VirtualBox . It should open VMDK images too. If not try to convert your disks using qemu-img :

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O vdi "%F" "%F.vdi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use:
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h

as indicated in: [VMWare can't find linux headers path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231876/vmware-cant-find-linux-headers-path)

works for me!