# vmplayer problem - VMWare Kernel Module Updater doesn't run since 13.04 upgrade

Tags: 13.04, kernel, vmware-player

When I run vmplayer, it detects that the kernel has changed, and as usual prompts compile and load the required modules.  However, it never gets any further.  When you choose install, it just quits silently with no error or any further action.  What should happen is that the VMWare Kernel Module Updater should run.  It doesn't.

Please note, this is not the same as the question answered here, [What is the path to the kernel headers so I can install vmware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware), which is due to the proper header files not being where they need to be.  Mine never gets this far, and besides, I made sure I have all the latest header files for my 3.8.0-19-generic  kernel.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found a fix for this problem.  The following will force it to fix itself

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you have to do this every time now.

Comment: +1 I can't tell you how many times I've had to google for this problem and come back to this answer.

Comment: in 15.10 this will result whit error: "Unable to install all modules.  See log for details."

Answer (score 8):

I have to do one thing before your fix that I got from here:
http://mergy.org/2013/03/three-tips-to-get-vmware-workstation-9-going-on-kernel-3-8-0/

So my complete fix has two steps and they would be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

On the first command change the linux headers version for the last version you have, in my case is 3.8.0-25 but i've been doing this since 3.8.0-19.