# VMware kernel module updater

Tags: vmware, linux-headers

This window pops up [VMware kernel module updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8LyD.png)

I tried many solutions, including this one [vmplayer problem - VMWare Kernel Module Updater doesn't run since 13.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288373/vmplayer-problem-vmware-kernel-module-updater-doesnt-run-since-13-04-upgrade?noredirect=1&lq=1).

If i do `sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-uname -r` i have this kind of error:

> The linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic package is not available, but is mentioned in the dependency list of another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, out of date, or
>   available from sources not mentioned in sources.list

And if i do `cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux` then gives an error that there is no such directory.

My `uname -r` = 4.13.0-36-generic.
If you need additional information, please write.