# Kernel Headers 3.10.18 not found in VMware Kernel Module Updater

Tags: kernel, vmware-player

I had Ubuntu 14.10 and VMware Player 7.0.0 installed on my Acer Chromebook 11. Wwhen I open VMware, I get the exact same error message as mentioned this thread - "[What is the path to the kernel headers so I can install vmware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware?newreg=79b443032c2e4d498b84086ab72906b0)", except it is "Kernel Headers 3.10.18", not "2.6.38-8-generic". I tried every suggestion in that thread, but to no avail. Can someone please help me?

Your suggestion is much appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The version file is not in the relevant folder, so this command should help with the issue.

```
cp /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/
```