# Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.10.18

Tags: kernel, vmware

I'm trying to use VMWare Player on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but encountering the same issue as discussed in ["Kernel Headers 3.10.18 not found in VMware Kernel Module Updater"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584490/kernel-headers-3-10-18-not-found-in-vmware-kernel-module-updater).

However I cannot seem to find the corresponding linux headers for 3.10.18, these do not appear when searching in the terminal or in Synaptic. Is anyone able to suggest how I can resolve this issue or provide a work around? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The officially supported kernels for Precise are 3.2 and 3.13. Why do you want to install 3.10? It is not supported, and never was.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a linux novice...

When I'm trying to launch VMWare Player I get the error message "Kernel headers for version 3.10.18 were not found" and asks for me to browse to the location of them in order to install them.

I basically just want to be able to use VMWare Player...

Comment: Okay, what is the output of the command `uname -a`?

Comment: Sorry I'm using chroot on my Chromebook to run this version of Ubuntu, so unable to directly copy and paste any output - but I can confirm the command confirms "Linux localhost 3.10.18 ..."

Comment: Then you are using an unofficial kernel. You need to ask whoever supplied it about how to install the headers.