# Kernel path error during VMware player 3.1.6-744570x86_64

Tags: kernel, vmware-player

Good Day Everyone

I'm trying to install VMWare player 3.1.6-744570x86_64 on Ubuntu (`uname -r` prints `3.19.0-25-generic`). I'm getting the [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJA7y.png) after running.
I did all steps from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware) but after provided correct path and  `+_Install` button click I'm still getting the [alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIBzE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do, is download a more current version of VMWare Player.  Version 12 (VMware-Player-12.0.1-3160714) of the player available at [this link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0) works well with Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Thank you a lot, Charles. This VMware Player version works great!