# problem to run vmware workstation 12 kernel header 3.19.0-49

Tags: software-installation, kernel, vmware, vmware-workstation

i have tried to install VMware workstation 12, but when i try to run it i don't know which kernel i may choose.
[Kernel problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ax0D.png)

i have a Linux system 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.

i have to examine this post
[What is the path to the kernel headers so I can install vmware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware)

i have tried to use `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.19.0-49-generic`, but i haven't obtain a result.

does anyone know the solution to this problem?
(it is my first question)